# VR Headset for mobile solutions (iOS\Android)

Tags: android, ios, iphone, virtual, virtual-reality

Is it possible to connect VR device such as Ocullus Rift or HTC Vive or another to smartphone?
I would like to develop VR app for both Android and iOS platform, but using external VR headset such as Oculus Rift, eg. via bluetooth or wifi.

The purpose of this is use mobile phone instead PC. Is it possible? Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Won't you have the problem that you cannot reach the performance you need for a smooth VR experience with a phone instead of a pc?

See https://support.oculus.com/170128916778795/ for the minimal specs for the Oculus. The phone with the most RAM right now out there has 8GB of RAM.

Besides that, how about battery life of the phone and the graphics chip?